# WIF3.5 - WIF4.5: Where do I set SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.TrustedEndpoints

Tags: c#, wif

I have to migrate a stack built on WIF 3.5 to WIF 4.5. It's a bit of a slow process, as I can't find much in the way of detailed documentation on this.

I've hit a blocker, and I can't seem to find how the SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.TrustedEndpoints were migrated. We have a Configuration class that extends SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration

```
MyConfiguration: SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration
```

In the Constructor there is some code that establishes a trusted endpoint:

```
//Add transport security message credential endpoint
this.TrustEndpoints.Add(new ServiceHostEndpointConfiguration(
            typeof(IWSTrust13SyncContract),
            new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
            "/mixed/username"));
```

I can't work out how to do the equivalent in WIF 4.5. Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from your config file:

```
<service name="System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="IWSTrust13" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13AsyncContract" bindingConfiguration="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration">
          <identity>
            <userPrincipalName value="yourUpn" />

          </identity>
        </endpoint>
<service/>
```

Then define the required binding.

```
<ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
```

You might need to associate that binding with a scheme. Hope this helps...